# CoordinatorLayout with different Toolbar behaviour

Tags: toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm having difficulty in implementing `CoordinatorLayout` as how to implement the `Toolbar` if some of my `Fragment`s have a different `Toolbar` behaviour. Say, that I have 5 fragments that would be shown in just one Activity (one fragment at a time). 2 of them would have a auto-hide `Toolbar` when scrolled, 1 with a simple `Toolbar` that's always showing even when scrolled, and 2 having `Toolbar` with `ImageView` inside `AppBarLayout` for parallax effect.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739806/coordinator-layout-with-toolbar-in-fragments-or-activity) only cover the auto-hide part, but not the parallax with image.

Some solutions that I could think of :

1. Have one `AppBarLayout` with `Toolbar` and `ImageView` in `Activity`. So if it displays a fragment that doesn't need the parallax effect, just set the `ImageView`'s visibility to GONE. But is it okay to do this? Because I got the feeling that it's not an appropiate solution.
2. Define `CoordinatorLayout` and `Toolbar` in each fragments' layout. But then I have to call `setSupportActionBar` everytime I'm displaying my fragment, when some of them actually have the same Toolbar.

Which is the best approach? Or maybe there is a better one than those two?

**UPDATE**
So, I ended up with number 2. I just add toolbars to each fragments' xml just like usual, nothing special. And in my BaseActivity I create a method to set the toolbar as action bar with some default configuration, so I won't have to duplicate the syntax to each of my fragments. Here's the method:

```
public void setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar, String title){
    if(toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(title != null);

        if (title != null) setActionBarTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: @user3289108 I set toolbars for each of my fragments' xml.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Looking for the same. Seems many Android devs doesn't know how to do it. It's very sad. Hope I'll find the solution.