# Is setSupportActionbar required anymore?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

With the new [Toolbar widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) introduced and it's AppCompat (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) version available, is it required to call setSupportActionbar(toolbar) anymore? Or is there any advantage of calling setSupportActionbar; as now we can set title, sub-title, navigation-icon, navigation-icon-click-listener (**getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) replacement**), menu, menu-click-listener (**options-menu replacement**) etc directly on the toolbar without ever calling setSupportActionbar.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ZakTaccardi/goodbye-actionbar-apis-hello-toolbar-af6ae7b31e5d

Comment: Thanks @eee ...so, we should "setSupportActionbar" only if we want to support older APIs like options-menu. Apart from this "setSupportActionbar" has no additional advantage?

Answer (score 6):

However [setSupportActionbar()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity?hl=en#setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)) method and [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBar) API remains [the documented way](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) of implementing an app bar, it looks rather as a way to use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) with the familiar API that developers are used to. In reality ActionBar API only complicates things often, take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@ZakTaccardi/goodbye-actionbar-apis-hello-toolbar-af6ae7b31e5d) for an example.

Nowadays, when a single activity architecture and [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) are recommended ways of implementing Android applications, it's very easy to [setup a fragment toolbar](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar) using [NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) library, for example:

```xml
<!-- my_fragment.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    ...
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:menu="@menu/my_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
  ...

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navController = findNavController()
    binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
    binding.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { ... }
  }
}
```

It's really that simple, as a result you'll get a toolbar with an auto set title, working back button and options menu. [Here](https://github.com/icesmith/android-samples/tree/master/SeparateToolbars) you can find the full GitHub sample which demonstrates a minimal Toolbar setup using NavigationUI.

So, there's no advantages of using ActionBar API at all? Maybe I'm wrong, but the only situation I see it useful is a single *app wide* toolbar. In this case you can put a toolbar into your activity and setup it differently in each fragment, for example by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. But by my experience toolbars tend to vary significantly between fragments so it's easier to have a separate toolbar for each fragment, the choice is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30739806/4858777). You can also take a look at the navigation component documentation: [Support app bar variations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations).