# Android Overlapping views and handle clicks

Tags: android, overlapping, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

So i have this activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My `mainContent` is where the fragments will inflate its views. In my particular case, the inflated fragment will have a recyclerview of cardviews.

The problem is, as it is, the layout looks as i want it to, like this:

[image]

But the navigation drawer icon is unclickable.  If i swap the coordinator layout with the framelayout, this happens:

[image]

And the navigation drawer becomes clickable but the icon cutted. I know i'm missing something here, i just cant figure it out.
I tried to put both inside a framelayout, but same output.

Comment: Could you please add your activity java codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button shouldn't be there.That's not what `MaterialDesign` Guidelines says.

You can use that `FloatingActionaButton` with a style like below:
https://github.com/xuyisheng/DesignSupportLibraryDemo

Or use it like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:onClick="checkin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

https://github.com/xuyisheng/DesignSupportLibraryDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml

And about that `FrameLayout`, as i see, you have `CoordinatorLayout` with that `FrameLayout` i think that FrameLayout us recognizing like `NavigationDrawer`.

Try to use it somewhere else.or use below answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035783/4409113