# how to create collapsing toolbar in fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Iam trying to create collapsing toolbar in my project for fragment and activity,
but the collapsing toolbar is not working well.Please help me find the solution, as iam new to android.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739806/coordinator-layout-with-toolbar-in-fragments-or-activity

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to create a AppBar layout as the main parent. Inside this add a CollapsingToolbarLayout. Inside CollapsingToolbarLayout add whatever you want inside your toolbar and finally the toolbar.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

<!--This can be anything, here I've added a view pager inside collapsing toolbar-->

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager_introduction"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/pager_item" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Now for the android part instantiate the toolbar and set it.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In my case I've added a viewpager, a seperate adapter will have to created to populate that viewpager.

Comment: Would you recommend putting the CollapsingToolbarLayout in the Activity or Fragment layout?