# Is it safe to use FragmentManager to replace the content of AppBarLayout for some fragments?

Tags: android, fragment

Main activity has a `CoordinatorLayout` in which there is an `AppBar` and a `FrameLayout` for fragments, a `NavigationView` and a `FloatingActionButton`.

We have more than 50 fragments. More than 40 fragments use the same simple toolbar/actionbar/appbar (truly annoying architecture, design, and naming by Google guys, and we still can't really differentiate them). They only need a back button, a simple title, and the icon for opening/closing navigation menu. The rest of the fragments have their own icons and might be taller.

We saw some questions, including this question:

[Coordinator Layout with Toolbar in Fragments or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739806/coordinator-layout-with-toolbar-in-fragments-or-activity)

Based on it, we decided to use a `FrameLayout` inside our main `AppBarLayout` and just like fragments, use `FragmentManager` to replace it for custom `AppBarLayouts`. Are we safe following this decision? We can't come to another solution for not repeating common toolbars across fragments.

Comment: So you want in different fragments a different icons and titles on the appBar?